# Need help splitting a string into 3 variables

Tags: python

I would like to split a string of characters into 3 variables. When I just run a `.split()` I get `['AAA00000011']`. I would like this to be split like:

```
var1 = AAA
var2 = 0000001
var3 = 1
```

The user is typing in these values into the command line on windows machine.

My Code:

```
barcode = raw_input('Please enter your barcode')

print "this is the barcode all split up", barcode.split()
```

Comment: What's the rule to split the string?

Comment: By what rule are you separating out the contents of var3? Is it the last digit?

Comment: You can do it with regular expressions, but the exact formatting your RE string should be is escaping me at the moment so I can't fill out an answer for you, sorry!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```
var1 = barcode[:3]   # first three characters
var2 = barcode[3:-1] # all characters from third to next-to-last
var3 = barcode[-1]   # last character
```

Comment: No in his example 'a' is the original string.  So you would do barcode[:3]

Comment: Thank you very much. I got it to work. You guys never stop amazing me :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use substrings here.

```
var1 = barcode[:3]
```

etc.

Comment: I think there's a little mistake: In the above code, `var1` would actually be `['AAA00000011']`.

Comment: @jena original is just the value that everyone else is referring to "barcode" as.  var1 = barcode[:3], which is a substring of the 1st 3 characters.

Comment: Nope, its not. :) It the sub list 0:3.

Comment: You are right, I don't know why I left the [] in there.  I kept reading just the single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Could also do it with an re (apologies, my re usage is rusty):

```
In [3]: re.findall('(\w{3})(\d{7})(\d)', 'AAA00000011')
Out[3]: [('AAA', '0000001', '1')]
```

Comment: us \w in the first section, and \d in the second.. will give you all alpha-letters and all digits respectively.

Comment: and make it .findall and change the parenthesis to <> and you should get the list of all three without the leading and following '' ? <-- not as sure about this fix.

Comment: I think run-time with the first change is exactly the same.. but at the very least is saves you from writing a couple extra characters in the future!